# Items won't show up in legend

Tags: arcgis-desktop, legend

I've imported some values attached to x y coordinates and am trying to display them as charts. All has gone well apart from the values displayed on the charts won't appear in the legend. I've exported the x y feature class I created into a new shapefile but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the only way, but when dealing with attributes and legends (or text boxes) we always export the values to a Excel file, then make the text box look as you want (also remove the grid lines in excel)  then you can copy and paste the excel file into a graphic editing program (photoshop, illustrator, even mspaint if thats all you have)  and create a graphic at the required dpi.  Then insert the graphic into your map.

This is assuming you want a graphic with a white background, you can always change colors a bit in the graphic program.  Then throw a nice neatline around the item and set your gaps to 0.  Like i said there are probably better ways but this how we do it.

Comment: just to add onto this answer. you can insert an excel table into ArcGIS using Insert>Object>Microsoft 97-2003 Worksheet. This will allow you to consume the windows dialogue into ArcGIS and update as needed (manually of course, but still a move in the right direction)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Made a bar chart in excel showing all points and then copied and pasted to use as a legend, with labels shown on the map for reference.

Comment: Yes I forgot about the inserting an excel sheet directly, which is another way to do it.  Did the method work out ok for you?  If so you can accept the answer so others will know it worked.

Comment: Yep worked out OK in the end, although I thought there might be a way of bringing up the items in the legend. This compromise works fine though.